# Deserialize java Object from Class function

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

Lets imagine I have the following Java class:

```
public class ImaginaryClass implements Serializable {
    private List<SomeData> someData;
    private transient boolean isSynced;

    public ImaginaryClass() {
        this.load();
    }

    public void addSomeData(SomeData data) {
        this.someData.add(data);
        this.isSynced = false;
        this.save();
    }

    private void load() {
        // Deserialize "this" instance of the object
        this.isSynced = true;
    }

    private void save() {
        // Serialize "this" instance of the object
        this.isSynced = true;
    }
}
```

My goal is to encapsulate the serialization and deserialization of an objects instance within the objects own class. I have many classes to implement that require special "treatment" and therefore this is the easiest design I've come up with so far.

But, I'm running into problems, I can't reassign the reference `this` so I'm under the impression this is not going to work. In Java is my above example possible? How do I make this work?

Comment: I personally prefer a nested `Map<String, Object>` type of serialization, since that's more portable to common file types (json/yaml/xml/etc).

Answer (score 1):

You can't reassign `this`, what you do in a Serializable object is to serialize / de-serialize all non transient non static fields.

Your idea of creating a new instance of the object is not bad.

If you create a brand new object you should return it as a new reference, in this case you can either have a *factory* which builds the object by loading it from some persistent storage, like:

```
ImaginaryClass objImg = ImaginaryClassFactory.newInstace().loadImaginaryClass();
```

Or you can do that in a `public static` method in the class itself:

```
public class ImaginaryClass implements Serializable {
  public static ImaginaryClass load(){
     ....
  }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly when I'm looking for, but you're right this would work for encapsulating the serialization code.